# Android how to react when user scrolls scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout, tablerow

I've a scrollview in my layout and inside the scrollview I've a tablelayout. In this tablelayout I add five tablerows programmatically. Now I want to add further five tablerows if the user reach the fourth tablerow. The idea behind this is that I don't want to add all 10 tablerows at once at the beginning. Only if the user reach the fourth row the app should add the next five rows in the tablelayout.

Any idea how to do this, maybe someone have an short example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend ScrollView class and modify the onOverScrolled method, read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#onOverScrolled(int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean)).